# Why is barcode scanner reading wrong value from barcode

Tags: macos, barcode, barcode-scanner, macos-catalina

I'm using Voyager barcode scanner (MS9540) with my mac
Version: 10.15.1 Beta (19B77a)

Prerequisites: i just plug scanner into usb port and nothing happend it start working

Problem: When i'm trying to read some barcode (string value: OpTTKK123456789) it will read as number: 079114086069083083123456789 (example).

The scanner is configured correctly (tested on windows - 2 different machines and it returns OpTTKK123456789).

Any hints?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So result is simple. In my case you need to skip ALT mode configuration step. I was unable to find why in documentation of scanner but it start working. So in future please really check if config for scanner is correct for your system.